# Transform/map json to another format

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Have long JSON object and small part is below:

```
const valueObject = {zipCode: 12345, street1: 'street 1', street2: 'street 2',city:'cityname', uniqueNum: '123456789'};
const mappingObject = {address: {pinCode: zipCode, addressLine1: 'street1', addressLine2:'street2', id: 'uniqueNum', city: city}
const formatObject = {address: {pinCode: '', addressLine1: '', addressLine2:'', id: '0', city: ''}
```

Trying to transform `valueObject` to `formatObject` using `mappingObject`.
(if `valueObject` has no value then use default value from `formatObject`)
It doesn't get work. Seems have a object and not an array. Not sure what is wrong here, Or does it need to merge.

```
Object.keys(formatObject).map((k)=>{k: valueObject[mappingObject[k]] || mappingObject[k]});
```

Output expected:

```
{address: {pinCode: 12345, addressLine1: 'street 1', addressLine2: 'street 2',city:'cityname', id: '123456789'};
```

In case, any better option through ES6 (
Else case, using for loop and prepare object. )

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. It seems your code will return an array. But you said you had an object instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, above code returning array.  but Need single object as `formatObject` , just values need to pick from `valueObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not need the `formatObject` here because the `mappingObject` gives the full transformation *schema*, i.e. the relation between two structures. `formatObject` merely serves as an example of what the possible output looks like.

A feasible implementation would be:

```js
function transform(schema, x) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(schema).map(([k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v === 'string') return [k, x[v]]
    else if (typeof v === 'object') return [k, transform(v, x)]
    else throw new TypeError(`Schema entry cannot have type ${typeof v}`)
  }))
}

transform(valueObject, mappingObject)
```

that works recursively through the schema to transform a flat-structured object (in this case `valueObject`) to a nested-structured object.

Comment: Thanks, `Object.fromEntries`  and `Object.entries` worked for me.